# Dual space of $C_b(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Due to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514569/what-is-the-relation-between-weak-convergence-of-measures-and-weak-convergence-f) I wonder if one knows the dual space of $C_b(X)$. Here $C_b(X)$ is the space of all continuous bouded functions with values in $\mathbb{R}$. Of course this depends on the space $X$ itself. One can assume that this space is nice, for example a complete separable metric space. It would be nice if we can exclude compactness of $X$. Is then anything known about the dual? In particular, we have for $P(X)$, the space of Borel probability measure on $X$, that $P(X)\subset C_b(X)'$, where the latter denotes the dual. The pairing is given by

$$\phi_\mu(f):=\langle \mu,f\rangle=\int fd\mu$$

which defines for every $f\in C_b(X), \mu\in P(X)$ bounded linear functional. But do we have "equality"? Are there example for structures of $X$ such that $C_b(X)$ is reflexive?

Comment: Have you heard, $C_b(X)\cong C(\beta X)$? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification.  That might help.

Comment: @JonasMeyer That could be an answer, with a very little fleshing out to pass the character limit.

Comment: I would  try to get this book: http://books.google.lt/books/about/Probability_Distributions_on_Banach_Spac.html?id=unJ5T5aa2fEC&redir_esc=y,

Comment: @JonasMeyer Using $C(\beta X)$ you would then use Riesz? The problem about applying Riezs is we get for a positive functional $\Lambda\in C(\beta X)'$ a finite positive Borel measure. In general I get signed measures which does not fit with $P(X)$. Moreover, $\beta X$ seems rather complicated to work with in application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See theorem 6 in section IV of Linear Operators: General theory volume 1 by Nelson Dunford and Jacob T. Schwartz.

The theorem says that for a normal topological space $X$ the continuous dual of $C_b(X)$ is isometrically isomorphic to the space $rba(X)$ of finititely additive regular bounded Borel measures on $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if one can strengthen the assumptions, such that we actually get $P(X)$ instead of $rba(X)$?

Comment: You can't get $P(X)$ as a dual of some space of functions, because $P(X)$ not even a linear space

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot.