# dual of the space $C(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, geometric-measure-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I was looking for the measure space which is the dual of the space $C(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ where $\Omega$ is bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The answer probably depends on the domain $\Omega$. Does the boundary of $\Omega$ have measure zero?

Comment: For nice boundaries (e.g. piecewise $C^1$) it's just $C_b(\Omega)$ - the space of bounded continuous functions, then this applies - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515403/dual-space-of-c-bx

Comment: Yes the boundary is of zero measure. @uniquesolution