# Are all linear functionals of probability measures continuous with respect to the Prokhrov metric?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $\mathcal{P}(X)$ be the set of all Borel probability measures on $X$, and $d_P$ be the Prokhorov metric on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ induced by $d$. We know that if  $X$ is separable, then convergence in $d_P$ is the same as weak convergence in $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

By weak convergence of $\mu_i\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ to $\mu\in\mathcal{P}(X)$, I mean

$$\forall f \in C_b(X),\;\; \int f\; d\mu_i \to \int f\; d\mu,$$
where $C_b(X) = \{f: X \to \mathbb{R}: f \text{ is continuous and bounded}\}$.

**My Question**: under the Prokhorov metric, are all linear functionals continuous?

Comment: A similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514569/what-is-the-relation-between-weak-convergence-of-measures-and-weak-convergence-f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Take $\ X=[0,1]\ $ and define $\ \ell:\mathcal{P}\big([0,1]\big)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $ by
$$
\ell(\mu)=\mu\Big(\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\Big)\ .
$$
Then $\ \ell\ $ is linear but not continuous.  If
$$
\mu_i(A)=\int_{A\cap\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{i}\right]}\left(2i+i^2-2i^2x\right)dx
$$
then $\ \mu_i\ $ converges weakly to $\ \delta_\frac{1}{2}\ $ (the probability measure with a single atom at $\ x=\frac{1}{2}\ $), but $\ \ell\big(\mu_i\big)=0\ $ for all $\ i\ $ and $\ \ell\left(\delta_\frac{1}{2}\right)=1\ $.

Comment: Thanks for the nice example. I also found a similar question and added the link above.